# like a visit or like visiting

Tags: word-usage

> I like a visit to this farm.
>
> I like visiting this farm.

As the word "like"  is transitive verb, can I use both usage, like a visit and like visiting?

Comment: What are you trying to say with "I like a visit to this farm."?

Comment: You'd probably say, "I would like to visit this farm." for your first sentence.  If you're already there then perhaps, "I am enjoying this visit to the farm." though that is awkward. The second is fine for expressing enjoyment in repeated visits to the farm.

Comment: I would like a visit to this farm. Would be better.

Answer (score -1):

You asked:
I like a visit to this farm.

I like visiting this farm.

I think both are fine, but used differently.
Because like a visit means you like to visit this farm, if you ask someone to visit their farm.
I think I like visiting this farm is like you did many times already, and you enjoyed visiting the farm.

Comment: The first sentence could mean "I like only one visit to this farm" which is not logical.